# Combine 'if' and 'if not' in perl

Tags: perl

I have got the following filter inside my `httpd.conf`:

```
ExtFilterDefine jsonfilter mode=output intype=application/json cmd="/usr/bin/perl -pe 's|^|qq(\,\") . valid . qq(\"\: ) . qq(\") . time() . \\x0D . qq(\") . qq(\\n)|e if ($==eof) &&  unless (-f q{/tmp/md5_filter.tmp})'"
```

But the way how I used the `&&` operater is not valid. I receive no output if I request the file. The filter should only run if the `md5_filter.tmp` file doesn't exists and `s` command should only add the timestamp at the `end of file (eof)`. Does somebody know what's wrong with my code?

Comment: Thanks. `valid` is just a simple string for the output of the requested json file.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of strange things about your code.

```
/usr/bin/perl -pe 's|^|qq(\,\") . valid . qq(\"\: ) . qq(\") . time() . \\x0D . qq(\") . qq(\\n)|e if ($==eof) &&  unless (-f q{/tmp/md5_filter.tmp})'
```

- `perl -pe`  does not actually change the file. Not sure if that is your intent. If you do want to change the file, you need to add the `-i` switch. Note that this will alter your file each time you run it.
- `s|` You have changed the delimiter of the substitution operator from `/` to `|`. This is usually done when you need to use slash `/` inside the pattern, and you want to avoid having to escape it `\/`. You however do not have slashes in your pattern, which makes this change unnecessary.
- `^` This denotes the start of a string. Your substitution will add from the beginning of the string. Since you want to add to the end of the file, I am not sure how you are thinking there.
- `qq(\,\") . valid . qq(\"\: ) . qq(\") . time() . \\x0D . qq(\") . qq(\\n)` You seem to be under the impression that the concatenation operator `.` does something special. This statement can be written `qq(,\"valid\": \") . time() . qq(\x0D\"\n)` Probably. The quoting and escaping is somewhat tricky to figure out. (No need to escape `,` and `:`)
- `if ($==eof)` is a weirdness beyond words. It means `$= = eof`, which assigns the return value of the `eof()` test to the [predefined `$=` variable](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar#$=) (The current page length). I feel pretty sure you didn't mean that, and only meant to check `if (eof)`.
- `if ($==eof) &&  unless (-f q{/tmp/md5_filter.tmp})` -- This is actually two separate statements, and you cannot use post-fix `if` twice in a row. Nor do you need to. You would chain them into one, like this: `if ( (eof) && (not -f q{...}) )`.

What do we get if we combine all these corrections? Well, we get this:

```
/usr/bin/perl -pe' s/^/qq(,\"valid\": \") . time() . qq(\x0D\"\n)/e if ( (eof) && (not -f q{/tmp/md5_filter.tmp}) )'
```

But.... what are you doing with this statement? For each line in the file, you are checking if it is the end of the file. And if it is, you check for the existence of a file, and then add to the last line, from the start of the line, a new string.

I *think* what you want to do is wait until the last line of the file, and then **print** a line after it. You don't need a substitution to print, you just print. So we remove the substitution and replace it with a print. Since we want to print after the last line, we use an `END` block to execute code at the end.

```
/usr/bin/perl -pe 'END { unless (-f q{/tmp/md5_filter.tmp}) { print qq(\,\"valid\"\: \") . time() . qq(\x0D\"\n) }'
```

The printed string may need to start with a newline `qq(\n...`, if the last line of the file does not end with a newline. If, for some reason, you actually meant to write the string at the beginning of the line, things get more complicated. Then you're probably better off using the first command.

Comment: Wow. I didn't expect such a great answer with all the details. Thank's a lot. My intent is not to change the requested file with `-i`. Just the output to change the md5 checksum for hacking tools like wpscan. With `if $==of` I just thougt to match the end of the file, not only the end of one line. My goal is, to add a timestamp at the end of file. I also tried to use `-0777pe` instead of `-pe` to treat the whole file as one single string/line. But it runs into an error for json files.

Comment: @cr4nk You're welcome. It may be that there is a better solution for that problem than using Perl. Consider asking a question about your main problem. It sounds a bit like an XY-problem.

Comment: Actually I am not a programmer. I am still learning all this stuff by myself. I am checking your code. Right know I got no output. Maybe some question marks not ok for my purpose. I am not sure. I receive this error in the browser by requesting a json file: `SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data`

Comment: You missed a `}` at the end of your code :-). It's now working for css files. And for json file, I receive the following error: `SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data at line 224 column 2 of the JSON data`. I guess because the string is added after the last brackets, so it's no valid json format anymore. I can't use your code this way. For json files, I need to replace the last closing `}` with `,"valid": "1639939750x0D"}`. How can I archieve it with your code? Do I need `s` substitution?

Comment: @cr4nk Yes, to insert you need a substitution. Probably you can replace the `^`  in your original substitution with `}\s*$`. If nothing is behind the last `}` except optional whitespace.

Comment: You should know that this is not the proper way to handle json. Again, you will get better answers by asking a proper question about json.